# Simplifying operation usage in Two's Complement Program

Tags: c

Specifically I'm trying to simplify this particular line of code by removing any of its operators with the limitation that I'm only allowed to use  `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`:

`int combine = ((sign << n) + ~sign + 1);`

Comment: What is the intent of that line of code?

Comment: and: this feels like homework.

Comment: also, you must remove it's operators, but you can replace them with the same operators you're already using? So don't do anything.

Comment: and you tell us nothing about what `sign` or `n` are. Kind of hard to give a general answer.

Comment: another pro hint: read the assembly your compiler produces.

Comment: Your question (and objective) are not clear. The code is simple enough. Do you want to use fewer operators? Or fewer distinct operators?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I want to use less operators and thought there may be some other way of achieving the same result this code produces using different logic.

Comment: @Marcus Müller: sign is the sign of modified string of bytes. n is the number of bits it is being shifted.

Comment: Wait a minute, why is there no subtraction in your list? Is that intentional (if so, is it for that one class whose professor always hands out this type of assignment and always leaves out subtraction?)

Comment: so, what is `sign` then? is it `0x0` or `0x1`, or is it `-1==0xF...E` or `0x1`, or something else completely?

Comment: @harold It is an unfortunate restriction placed on this particular exercise. It is indeed, evidently this is a bit of a rite of passage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It'll vary, but the program is able to handle 0x0 or 0x1.

Answer (score 4):

If you run this program a handful of times, with different values of `n`, there will be an OBVIOUS pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 4;
    for(int sign=1; sign<15; ++sign)
    {
        int combine = ((sign << n) + ~sign + 1);

        printf("%d => %d\n", sign, combine);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In each case, when:

```
n == 1, then combine == sign.
n == 2, then combine == 3*sign.
n == 3, then combine == 7*sign.
```

In general, for any N, `combine == ((2`<sup>`n`</sup>`)-1) * sign`

Now, can you find a fast way to express that relationship?

Are there any restrictions on values for `n` and `sign` that you haven't told us about?
 Or does it need to be solved for ***all*** values of `n` and `sign`?

Comment: You know that `2^n` is not "two to power n", don't you?

Comment: Its not in C... but I don't know a better way to write in when we don't have MathJax.  I feel my meaning is clear enough.

Comment: It's not clear at all, because `^` is a valid bit operator.  `1<<n`, right?

Comment: @DYZ I agree with abelenky that he made his point clear enough. Anyway, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I didn't know about that super-script formatting!

Comment: @abelenky yeah, it's handy at times, but I had to break the verbatim environment up, which isn't all that cool.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I respectfully disagree. When the whole answer uses the C notation, the only logical way to interpret `^` is as an XOR.

Comment: So how do you use this insight? I'm still not getting any further than `(sign << n) - sign`

Comment: Well, the good thing with humans is that they can get along without agreeing on everything, @DYZ :) I think that together with the pseudo-induction above, it's pretty clear, but it really doesn't matter now, does it?